# Заполнить и вывести матрицу с помощью js

Tags: javascript

Требуется создать двумерный массив 10х5 и заполнить его числами от 100 до 200, после вывести результат в виде таблицы (строки-столбцы) и отсортировать.
Испытываю трудности с JS: не получается заполнить массив, а результат выводится в одну строку.

```js
var arr = [
  [], [], [], [], []
];

for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
}

console.log(arr[1]);
```

Comment: SO существует не для решения домашних заданий.

Comment: я хочу узнать в чем ошибка моя

Comment: В том, что вы заполняете одномерный массив. Для заполнения двумерного массива явно должно быть два цикла.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, не обязательно

Comment: @Grundy обязательно. Их, конечно можно скрыть за map/forEach и т.п. но под капотом всё-тавно будет два цикла.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, конечно же нет

Comment: Мне уже любопытно :)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, есть формула перевода индексов из двумерного массива, в одномерный, а так же обратная ей. То есть, по текущему индексу можно определить строку и колонку куда надо положить элемент. Достаточно значить количество строк либо количество столбцов, в зависимости от того как нужно заполнять по строкам либо по столбцам

Comment: Типа `a[k div n][k mod n]`. Ну это какая-то ручная оптимизация уже

Comment: @AlexeyTen, но это все еще один цикл :-)

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте то ли это, что вам нужно - а то по вашему описанию очень сложно понять детали задачи.

```js
var cmpr = function(a, b) {
  if (+a > +b) {return 1} else {return -1}
}

var arr=[];
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  arr[i]=[];
  for(var j=0;j<10;j++){ 
    arr[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random()*(200-100+1))+100
  }
  arr[i].sort(cmpr)
}

 console.log(arr);
```

Comment: хотел бы узнать, например есть у нас многомерный массив как сделать так чтобы массивы внутри него выводились в столбик, как матрица например

Comment: @TheMarafonskiy куда "выводились"?

Comment: @TheMarafonskiy, 
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, '\t'));

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei, [console.table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/table)

Comment: @TheMarafonskiy, Non-standard
This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать с помощью рекурсий -

```js
// m - matrix
// x - horizontal size
// y - vertical size
const fillMatrix = ( matrix, horizontalSize, verticalSize, provider ) => {
 const horizontal = ( m, x, y ) => 
 m.push( provider( m.length, y ) ) < x ?  horizontal( m, x, y ) : m;

 const vertical = ( m, x, y ) => 
 m.push( horizontal( [], x, m.length ) ) < y ? vertical( m, x, y ) : m;

 return vertical( matrix, horizontalSize, verticalSize );
}

let matrix = fillMatrix( [], 3, 3, (x, y) => ({ x, y }) )
let string = matrix.reduce( ( vertical, item ) => {
 vertical += item.reduce( ( horizontal, { x, y } ) => {
  horizontal += `[x: ${ x }, y: ${ y }]`;

  return horizontal;
 }, "");
 vertical += "\n";

 return vertical;
} , "" );

console.log( string );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRand() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
}

var arr = [
    for (r of new Array(5))[
        for (c of new Array(10)) getRand()]
];
console.log(arr);
```

Забыл про сортировку

`var arr = arr.map(el => el.sort((a, b) => a - b));`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = new Array(10);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr[i] = new Array(5);
}


for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```